# Google Apps Reseller API daily usage limit is less than shown in developers console?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I started to test an application that use the Google Apps Reseller API and, after 1k requests, Google APIs started to send the error:

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Daily Limit Exceeded",
    "reason" : "dailyLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "Daily Limit Exceeded"
}
```

At the developer console, I see that I used 10% of the 10k daily requests courtesy.

As the application is doing some batch requests, I am not sending either `userIp` or `quotaUser` in the requests. Also, I already changed the `per user limit` to 10,000 requests/second/user.

Is there anything I can do to use the full 10k requests? In this testing phase, it is important.

Answer (score 0):

In our project the problem was resolved through Google Support. It is an Google internal issue, nothing you can fix yourself.